# Design Question for Notification System

Tags: algorithm, search, search-engine, web-crawler

The original post was posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007097/design-question-for-notification-system

Here is more clarification of the problem: The notification system purpose is to get user notified (via email for now) when content of the site has changed or updated, or new posting is made. This could be treated as a notification system where people define a rule or keyword for 3rd party site and notification system goes out crawle 3rd party site and crate search inverted indexes. Then a new link or document show up for user defined keyword or rule (more explanation at bottom regarding use case),

For clarified used case: Let suppose I am craigslist user and looking for used vehicle. I define a rule “Honda accord”, “year “ 1996 and price range from “$2000 to $3000”.

For above use case to work what is best approach and how can I leverage on open source technology such as Apache Lucent, Apache Solr and Apache Nutch, and Apache Hadoop to solve this use case.
You can thing of building search engine and with rule and keyword notification system. I just need some pointers and help on how to integrate these open source package to solve use case ?

Any help and pointer will be appreciated. We need three important components are :

```
1) Web Crawler 
2) Index Creator  
3) Rule or keyword Mather
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I was referring this wiki which integrates Nutch and Solr together for above purpose http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/RunningNutchAndSolr

Comment: This is a very wide-ranging request, not something that is easily answered. I suggest you come up with some more specific, concrete questions. Have you started implementing this system? Do you have any specific tech requirements (i.e. only using java, mongodb etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a big one but I'll take a stab at it as I've designed and implemented systems like this before.

Ignoring user account management, your system will need to provide the means to:

1. retrieve new prospect data (web spider)
2. identify  and extract pertinent results from prospect data (filtering)
3. collect, maintain and organize results (storage)
4. select results based on various metadata (querying)
5. format results for delivery to users (templating)
6. deliver formatted results to users (delivery)

If the scope of your project is small (say less than 100 sites requiring spidering per day), you could probably get along with one of the many open-source web spiders including wget, Nutch, WebSphinx, etc. You might need to provide instrumentation (custom software) for scheduling, monitoring and control. If your project scope is larger than this, you may need to "roll your own" spidering solution (custom software). Typically this would be designed as a distributed, parallel architecture.

For simple filtering, regular expressions would suffice but for more complex tasks requiring knowledge of HTML layout (extract the textual component of the fifth list element (`<LI/>`) of the fourth table on the page) you'd need to use an XHTML parser. However you proceed, you'll need to provide custom software to conduct filtering based on your users' needs.

While any database technology can be used to store results extracted from retrieved documents, using an engine optimized for text like Apache SOLR will allow you to easily expand your search criteria as your needs dictate. Since SOLR supports the attachment of and search for metadata associated with each document, it would be a good choice. You'll also need to provide custom software here to automate this step.

Once you've selected a list of candidate results from SOLR, any scripting language could be used to template them into one or more emails and would also inject them into your mail transport agent (MTA). This also requires custom software to automate this process (and if required, to inject user-specific data into each message).

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look at Google's Custom Search API also before diving into crawling the web yourself. This way, google can help you with returning keyword based search results, which you could later filter in your application based on your additional algorithms/rules etc, and make the whole thing work.